# Why do not undeclared props pass to the components's root element?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I made a wrapper around Vuetify's **'v-dialog'** component named **'Modal'** and wanna pass props through it:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
    class="modal"
    max-width="600"
    v-on="vDialogListeners"
  >
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title class="headline">
        <slot></slot>
      </v-card-title>
    <v-card>
      ...
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

I use it like this (**'value'** prop):

```
<Modal
  :value="showModal"
  :confirm="true"
  @close="onModalClose"
  @click:outside="onModalClose(false)">
Are you sure you'd like to log out?
</Modal>
```

I know about **$attrs** and it works if I bind it explicitly, i.e, `v-bind="$attrs"` within `<v-dialog>` opening tag.

My question: why doesn't work it by default, that's without explicit `v-bind="$attrs"`, if `<v-dialog>` is the component's root element and should accept all props undeclared in the component, or I'm wrong and misunderstand this part of documentation?
I used to think that `v-bind="$attrs"` is only used in case `inheritAttrs: false` in order to pass udeclared props to a component's not-root element (a nested one).

I have a guess: maybe, it only concerns the components root html element (e.g., input tag) by default.

Comment: So if you do not have a `value` prop definition, it would land up in `attrs` of Modal instead of props.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It seems I figured out the proper usage of it. By default, it adds these '$attrs' to the DOM element as attributes; by explicit binding, I can pass them to the necessary child component; by setting `inheritAttrs = false`, I cancel the default behavior of adding attributes to the DOM element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I figured out the proper usage of it. By default, it adds these `$attrs` to the DOM element as attributes. By explicit binding, I can pass them to the necessary child component. By setting `inheritAttrs = false`, I cancel the default behavior of adding attributes to the DOM element. Thus, I can combine these options to get the suitable behavior.